# Calling C DLL from Delphi program

Tags: delphi, dll, parameters, type-conversion

In my Delphi code I have to call a DLL's function (written in Visual C) with the following prototype:

```
int PWFunc(LPCSTR szName, int nWidth, int nHeight, LPCSTR szFileName)
```

How can I convert Delphi AnsiString variables (for Name and FileName) into right type parameters (LPCSTR szName and szFileName) of function call ?
I know that VC LPCSTR type corresponds to Delphi PAnsiChar type, but what is the right procedure to convert AnsiString to PAnsiChar ?

Comment: `PAnsiChar(AnsiString(s))` is the answer to your last Q, assuming the encoding is ANSI. If the encoding is UTF-8, different answer!

Comment: @henry, what version of Delphi are you using ? At least in Delphi 2009 there's the `LPCSTR` type defined...

Comment: And if the encoding is UTF-8 what is the difference ?

Comment: For UTF-8 encoding, you can pass a parameter value like `PAnsiChar(AnsiString(UTF8Encode(s)))` or directly `LPCSTR(AnsiString(UTF8Encode(s)))`, if you define the prototype by using `LPCSTR` data type. Or even without the conversion to `AnsiString`, like `PAnsiChar(UTF8Encode(s))` or `LPCSTR(UTF8Encode(s))`.

Comment: What have you tried, yourself? I'm quite sure your first or second attempt would produce the desired result...

Comment: You'll need to know the calling convention too

Comment: The code with features You suggested has different behaviours under Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2003; it's working correctly under 2008 but strings are'nt passed correctly under 2003.

Comment: Both with PAnsiChar and with LPCSTR... Do You have sime suggestions about this ?

Comment: Please explain how you diagnosed that. You've only described one side of the interface.

Comment: By log of called program (by dll); in 2008 passed strings are correctly recognized and program is working, but in 2003 they are'nt, sometimes substituted by 1...

Comment: Show the code on the other side of the interface. Rudy's translation is fine and behaves the same way on all operating systems. So, there's something wrong with the information that we have.

Answer (score 2):

`LPCSTR` and `LPSTR` correspond to `PAnsiChar`, so that is what you use:

```
function PWFunc(szName: PAnsiChar; nWidth, nHeight: Longint;
  szFileName: PAnsiChar): Longint; cdecl { or stdcall, see documentation };
  external 'somedll.dll' name 'PWFunc';
```

You call it like:

```
X := PWFunc(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(SomeName)), 17, 33, 
       PAnsiChar(AnsiString(SomeFileName)));
```

Whether your function is `stdcall` or `dcecl` depends on compiler settings. Read the documentation. If in doubt, try both. It looks like `cdecl` to me, so start with that.

Comment: +1 But I'd argue that Integer is the correct translation for C int.

Comment: Well, indeed, but we know that it is a 32 bit integer, and in such cases, when interfacing with other languages, I prefer to use fixed size types.

Comment: You say one thing but do another. Read your answer one more time. Also, C int is not fixed size. So, int32_t would match Longint. The best match for int is Integer.

Comment: You might like to read this article: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html

Comment: In C, `int` can have various sizes. In C on Windows and even on OS X (either 32 or 64 bit) however, `int` is 32 bits in size, and thus, `Longint` is the better choice, IMO. I think I have read the article you mentioned. <g>

Comment: You say one thing but do another. Your answer contradicts itself. Your article disagrees with what you say here. FWIW, Delphi Integer matches C int on all platforms. For 16 bit Windows,  C int is 16 bit.

Comment: I don't see a contradiction, sorry. And I know the article. I changed my mind since then.

Comment: The contradiction is where you map to Integer sometimes, and Longint at other times.